# Accessing a login api using http get method in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, https

I am developing an android app which uses a login api, which will allow its web users to login with their same credentials on the android device.....

the url for the api is

```
https://api.ecoachsolutions.com/main.php?ecoachsignin=1&server=remote&user=ecoachguest&pass=ecoachguest
```

which retuns a response in json

```
JSON object: {
    status: <success or error>,
    msg: <response message>,
    profile: <user profile object> 
}
```

I tried this code which I found searching on the internet but it isn't working,

```
private void doLogin(View view) {
    //ALERT MESSAGE
          _spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "connecting to server.... ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    // URLEncode user defined data


    String usernameValue   = username.getText().toString();

    String passValue    = password.getText().toString();


    // Create http cliient object to send request to server

    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Create URL string

    String URL = "https://api.ecoachsolutions.com/main.php?ecoachsignin=1&server=remote&user="+usernameValue+"&pass="+passValue;

    Log.i("httpget", URL);

    try
    {
        String SetServerString ;

        // Create Request to server and get response
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        System.out.println(usernameValue);
        System.out.println(passValue);
        // Show response on activity

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),SetServerString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        _spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


}
```

will appreciate the help or the positive direction thanks :)

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: `the url for the api is`. Please add https:// as you omitted very important info.  `but it wasn't working`. You are supposed to tell exactly what not worked. Specifying errors and posting parts of the logcat.

Comment: first of all how do i get the response in Json and it returns fail when i try logging in

Comment: No. First of all you tell wich errors you have now. You can find them in the logcat. Please post them. You can consider this `the positive direction` ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to get the `HttpResponse` like below,

```
        String responseBody = "";

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        Log.i("GET Response Code ",responseCode + "");

        switch(responseCode) {
        // Means server is responding
        case 200:    
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null) {
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                // Now you can try printing your returned string here, before you go for JSON parsing
            }
            break;
        // Add more case statements to handle other scenarios
        }
```

The code is simple, but if still unable to understand, don't hesitate to ask.