# Get Login Token from WebSite via an API

Tags: java, android, api, authentication, android-asynctask

im trying to create a LoginActivity in Android.
I use the standard LoginActivity template provided by Android Studio.

What i wana do is give the user a nice LoginActivity, and when the login is successful an Activity with WebView showing the WebSite should be shown.

Now i have an Asynchron Task where all the "magic" seems to happen.

```
 public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.



        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }



        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Here the username and password is simply compered to values of an Array.

My first Problem is, everything i change of that Task, like adding a simple Toast, leads my App to crash...

This is my first time implementing a login, but am i right that my login algorihm has to be insige that task?

Thats my naxt Question, how do i make a request, using an empty login-token for my r and call the function getLoginToken?

The API from this Site gives me this RequestLink:

```
www.pentle.com/api.php?c=json&r={"request":"getLoginToken","validation":{"type":"token","client":"YOUR_APP","token":"","token_id":0,"user_id":0}}&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

The request will return a json object like this:

```
{
   "token_id":0,
   "user_id":0,
   "token":"THE_TOKEN"
}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253885/accessing-a-login-api-using-http-get-method-in-android) Solution but it didnt Work. When i try to use the `HttpClient` it has a line going through it (struck through / crossed out?). And my App crashes...

Maybe somebody can shed some light on how to use an Asynchron Task, and how to make a login possible with the RequestLink.

It is realy important for me that this is working!

EDIT:
Thanks to @danny my code looks like this now:

```
package com.pentle.pentle2;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    public String test = "";

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
};
/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}

private void populateAutoComplete() {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;


    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for empty Username
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return password.length() > 4;
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            // Select only email addresses.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                    " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
            .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

            // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
            // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

}

private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
    };

    int ADDRESS = 0;
    int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
}


private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
    //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

    mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;


    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
        test = "1";
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
    String response;
    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try
        {
            test = "2";
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("www.pentle.com/api.php?c=json&r={request:getLoginToken,validation:type:token,client:Pentle_Android,token:,token_id:0,user_id:0}}&username="+mEmail+"&password=" + mPassword);
            //_email and _password are String values from TextView:
            test = "3";
            //postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity("&username="+mEmail+"&password=" + mPassword));
            test = "4";
            postMethod.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            //here is the reponse, you can check it:
            response = Client.execute(postMethod, responseHandler);

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Login to server failed...
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



        /*try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }*/

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
    }
}
```

Later it should return if the user wasnt foud, the user was found but the pw was incorrect, or if the login was successful. In case of it beeing successful an Activity with a WebView shoul be displayed.

Right now it fails at `HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("www.pentle.com/api.php?c=json&r={request:getLoginToken,validation:type:token,client:Pentle_Android,token:,token_id:0,user_id:0}}&username="+mEmail+"&password=" + mPassword);`. Does it becasue im trying to run it in Background? 
The String `test` is displayed in a Toast in `PostExecute` to see where ist stops.

Did i use the API Request right?

Comment: Have you tried some libraries like volley? give it a chance: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: Do you want to see my code with token, but implemented with other Thread not AsynTask?

Comment: @ Tofasio: I haven't tried other libraries, but will maybe give it a try, thanks!     @ danny: Sure! Anything that helps! For some time now im considering to make my own LoginActivity completely from scratch and not using the provides one. But when clicking the Login-Butten it gives me this nice Progress spinner :D

Comment: @danny: Do you need my E-Mail or do you want to post it here?

Comment: @DenisPramme, please paste error message at this line.

Comment: @DenisPramme Please paste all your code in this Activity.

Comment: @danny: thats a funny thing, i dont get any Error :) I enabled my ADB integration but i dont get any logcat or Error messages...

Comment: Edited in all Code from this Activity

Answer (score 0):

@Denis Pramme

Please try this code and let me know:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
.....

private void SignInMethod()
{
 new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        try
          {
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("*URL TO YOUR API SERVER*" +   "Authenticate");
        //_email and _password are String values from TextView:
        postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=password&username=" + _email + "&password=" + _password));
        postMethod.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //here is the reponse, you can check it:
        response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, resonseHandler);
          }

          catch(Exception ex)
          {
           //Login to server failed...
             ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    }).start();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Edited my Post! It doesn't work, maybe i did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@DennisPramme, ok please change the line:

```
String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, resonseHandler);
```

TO this line: (it will show status returned from server):

```
HttpResponse responseFromServer = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
int status = responseFromServer.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: This is error on server side so you will receive exception message empty.